# Cannot fit all of data read from AWS S3 - output buffer too small

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to load data into redshift from AWS.
The file very small, 46 MB. Everytime, I tried to load the data I got the erorr:

ERROR: XX000: Failed writing body (0 != 16384) Cause: Cannot fit all of data read from s3 - output buffer too small

I searched but could not find anything. Has anybody faced this or know the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.
The encoding of the next file was different than the one I was using in the copy command.